# Regex and matching all all of text and not substring

Tags: regex

I have regex that matches that matches on 1 or 3 small characters and one full stop. 
Here is the Regex.

```
([a-z]{1,3}[.]{1})
```

I want the regex to only match the text i give it and not substrings of the text. eg

Only match `abc.`

Do not match `abcdef.` So do not match `def.` because its a substring.

Comment: sub string of what, all the text, a word?

Comment: `\b[a-z]{1,3}\.` maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add start `^` and end `$` anchors:

```
^([a-z]{1,3}[.]{1})$
```

---

Incidentally, you don't need the `{1}` - that's implied. This is the same as your regex:

```
^([a-z]{1,3}[.])$
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bohemian's answer. +1 for that. However anchors work only for an entire string. If the text you want to match is a part of a string like `def asd jkl ljk abc. asdf` and still you want to match `abc.` here, then you could use

```
[^a-z][a-z]{1,3}\.
```